# React-admin: Can I truncate a <TextField> within a <List>?

Tags: react-admin

**Is there a way to truncate text returned by the `<TextField>` and show `...`?**

See **title** column within image below (I want to truncate the title after 20 chars).

Is there a specific `prop`? Unfortunately, I didn't find any clue within the react-admin doc.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can actually manipulate any field outside a `<List>`,**
and then get the `<Datagrid>` to render that field, as long as it's iterative.

```js
const CustomTitleField = ({ record }) => {
  // "record" is a prop received from the Datagrid
  let str = record.title;
  return record ? (
    {/* If length is greater than 20 characters, slice and add ellipsis.*/}
    <span>{str.length > 20 ?  str.slice(0, 20) + "..." : str}</span>
  ) : null;
};

// Then, within your list, do this...
export const CommentList => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
      <CustomTitleField /> // this should render with your truncate logic
      // ...
    </Datagrid>
   </List>
);
```

Let me know how it goes, after try this out!!

Comment: Thank you so much mate

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cellClassName` to customize the cell style inside a `Datagrid`.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#styling-fields

I had a similar question and here is what works for me.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tableHeader: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textTransform: "capitalize",
  },
  tableCell: {
    maxWidth: 300,
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    overflow: "hidden",
  }
}));

const MyList = ({ ...props }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <List
      {...props}
    >
      <Datagrid>
        <TextField
          headerClassName={classes.tableHeader}
          cellClassName={classes.tableCell}
          source="detail"
          label="Detail"
        />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

Comment: This should be best answer, since the length is not hardcoded.